# Calculating KLD for every element of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an actual data-frame (df) of columns=2000 and rows=10000. For simplicity, I will describe my problem with a dummy df of 1 row and 10 columns. I want to calculate the KLD for each cell of the df. Each index of every row is divided by the sum of that row, so that if I consider `row1` as a vector then it will sum up to `1`. For calculating Kullback-Leibler divergence (KLD) we need 2 vectors summing up to 1. In my case to calculate the KLD for `df[1,1]` the `vector1` will be the first row and the `vector2` will have the same length as `vector1` (10) where index 1 will contain the value `1` while all other values will be `0`.

```
df <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)

KLD <- function(A, B) {
        sum(A * ifelse(B > 0, log(A/B), 0))
    }

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

KLD(vector1, vector2)
```

Similarly, for calculating KLD of `df[1,2]`, vector1 will again be the row1 and vector2 will be a vector of length 10 where index 2 will be 1 while all other values will be 0.

```
vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

KLD(vector1, vector2)
```

And so on, I caculate KLD for every every element in the df.

Can anybody help me with this, how can I iterate this function to every index of df. Your help will be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Following will be the total no.of steps for calculating the KLD of every index of my df

```
vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

vector1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
vector2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Here you can see that for row1 the vector1 stays the same everytime, it is just the vector 2 which changes.

```
final output will be something like: 

output
 [1] -0.2297388 -0.1297385 -0.1051967 -0.2051999 -0.1051975 -0.1853967 -0.1151998 -0.1051967 -0.2251954 -0.1651990
```

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/

Comment: @Vincent Thanks. But how do I make such ´vector2´ every time?

Comment: Is your desired result for one row i = 1 to 10 `sum(Ai*Log(Ai))` (apologies for the poorly formatted sum formula)

Comment: @Mako212 Sorry I didn't understand what you're suggesting here!! Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how `vector2` plays into your formula. Because when `vector2[i] == 1` your formula simplifies to `sum(A*log(A))`, and when `vector2[i] == 0` your formula returns zero. It sounds like you're trying to calculate KLD for `df[1, i]` where `vector2[i] == 1` for each element `df[1, i]`. If that's the case, then you don't need `vector2` at all, because you can ignore every case where `vector2 == 0` since the result will be zero anyway.

Comment: @Mako212 If I understood you correctly, No, It will be the sum of the given input vector (A) multiplied with log(values in vector A / values in vector B); if corresponding value in B is not 0, otherwise it will be 0.

Comment: @Newbie Was your result computed after your example ? I don't understand how you can get different values with a repetition of 0.03. Shouldn't values 2 to 10 be identical in the output ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe `df` :

```
row1 <- c(0.73, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
row2 <- c(0.64, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04)
df<-rbind(row1,row2)
```

And a set of vectors, which you will be wanting to use a input for your KLD calculation for each row of df :

```
vector1<- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
vector2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
vectors<-rbind(vector1,vector2)
```

You can make the calculation for each row of `df` and, say, `vector1` using `apply()` :

```
KLD <- function(A, B) {
  sum(A * ifelse(B > 0, log(A/B), 0))
}

apply(df,1,FUN=KLD,B=vector1)
```

And you can do that for each vector of the set using a nested `apply()` :

```
metaKLD <- function(vect) {
  apply(df,1,FUN=KLD,B=vect)   # this makes the calculation for each row of df with a given vector
}

apply(vectors,1,FUN=metaKLD)    # this makes it happen for each vector of the set
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking out the time to look into this.
I think may be I was not clear enough in explaining the problem. There are 2 things missing in your solution. First, this KLD formula will be applied to every cell in the df, so that the output I get will have the same dimensions as the input df. Secondly, the part which I don't understand is how I will generate such vectors that they have value 1 corresponding to the value of input vector. Please see question again, I have edited it.